# SQL Statement Output in incorrect Order, not sure why?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

For some reason the code below is returning the results, put not in the correct order.

Anyone have any ideas why as I have been looking at it for a couple of hours and have yet to spot the problem:

```
USE [storeboard]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [sbuser].[sp_MemberMailList ]    Script Date: 11/25/2011 12:04:15 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROC [sbuser].[sp_MemberMailList ]
    @MemberMailID bigint = null,
    @FromMemberID bigint = null,
    @ToMemberID bigint = null,
    @Subject varchar(150) = null,
    @Message varchar(8000) = null,
    @FromDeletedFlag bit = null,
    @ToDeletedFlag bit = null,
    @FromArchivedFlag bit = null,
    @ToArchivedFlag bit = null,
    @ReadFlag bit = null,
    @SQL nvarchar(4000) = null,
    @SortField varchar(100) = null,
    @SortOrder varchar(25) = null,
    @NotificationSent bit = null,
    @MemberID bigint = null,
    @OnHold bit = 0,
    @SpecialMail varchar(1) = 'N',
    @PageSize float = null,
    @PageNum int = 1,
    @TotalPages float = null,
    @StartDate datetime = null,
    @EndDate datetime = null,
    @MODE varchar(50)

AS

IF @MODE = 'INBOX-MAIL-NOSORT'
    BEGIN
        SELECT @TotalPages = CEILING(COUNT(*)/@PageSize)
        FROM MemberMail
        WHERE ToMemberID = @ToMemberID
        AND ToDeletedFlag = 0
        AND OnHold = 0
        AND ToArchivedFlag = 0
        AND FromDeletedFlag = 0;

        WITH InMailsCDDESC AS
        (

            SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY a.CreateDate DESC) AS RowNum,
            a.MemberMailID,     -- 1
            a.FromMemberID,     -- 2
            a.Subject,          -- 3
            a.CreateDate,       -- 4
            b.UserName,         -- 5
            a.ToReadFlag,       -- 6
            b.Firstname,        -- 7
            b.Lastname,         -- 8
            b.MemberDisplayName AS DisplayName, -- 9
            @TotalPages AS TotalPages -- 10
            FROM MemberMail a
            INNER JOIN Member b ON b.MemberID = a.FromMemberID
            WHERE a.ToMemberID = @ToMemberID
            AND a.ToDeletedFlag = 0
            AND a.OnHold = 0
            AND a.ToArchivedFlag = 0
            AND a.FromDeletedFlag = 0
        )
        SELECT * FROM InMailsCDDESC
        WHERE RowNum BETWEEN (@PageNum - 1) * @PageSize + 1 AND @PageNum * @PageSize
    END
```

Any help you can provide would be greatly appreciated.
Many thanks,
Paul

Comment: You don't specify any `ORDER BY` - so SQL Server doesn't reutrn the data ordered by anything ... if you need order, specify `ORDER BY`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want a specific order you need to use an `ORDER BY` in your SELECT statement.

As you don't specify an `ORDER BY` in your SELECT statement, the database is free to return the rows in any order it likes.

**Edit**

I'm adding Lamak's comment to make this answer complete:

The `ORDER BY` in the definition of the window for `row_number()` is only used to to calculate result of the `row_number()` function. It is not used to sort the overall result (which is part of the beauty of windowing functions)

To order by the calculated `row_number()` you need to add an `ORDER BY RowNum` to the final SELECT statement.

Comment: ORDER BY is specified: SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY a.CreateDate DESC) AS RowNum... do I have to add it somewhere else..?

Comment: @neojakey - That `ORDER BY` is only to calculate the `ROW_NUMBER`, it doesn't order the rows that is returning. For that, you need to add an `ORDER BY RowNum` at the end of your query

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to add the orderby in your final select statement, possibly order by rownum?